# Show Positive-Definiteness of Symplectic Form

Tags: mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Here's a baby example I'm working on:

> Consider the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the symplectic form $dp\wedge
>  dx$ where clearly the space is parameterized by $(x,p)$.  For fixed
>   $\alpha > 0$ consider the coordinate $z = x -i\alpha p$ and the
>   corresponding tangent vector  $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \;\;
>  =\;\; \frac{1}{2}\left (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{i}{\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \right ). $$ Consider the
>   polarization $P$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the span of the vector
>   $\partial_z$.  This gives rise to a complex polarization (i.e. $P_z
>  \cap \overline{P_z} = \{0\}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$).  Given the
>   mapping $J:T_z\mathbb{R}^2 \to T_z\mathbb{R}^2$ where $J_z(\partial_z)
>  = i\partial_z$ and $J_z(\partial_{\overline{z}}) = -i\partial_{\overline{z}}$, show that $\omega(X,JY)$ is positive-definite.

I've tried showing this a couple of different ways but to no avail.  I'm pretty new to symplectic geometry and I'm pretty sure there's just some small detail I'm missing.

If I complexify the whole problem, we can see that the isomorphism under $\omega$ shows us that $dp = -(dz + d\overline{z})$ and $dx = -i\alpha(dz - d\overline{z})$ and therefore
$$
\omega \;\; \equiv \;\; dp\wedge dx \;\; =\;\; 2i\alpha (d\overline{z}\wedge dz).
$$

However taking a vector $X = a\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$ we can easily compute that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\omega(X,JX) & = & \omega \left (a\partial_z + b \partial_{\overline{z}}, ia\partial_z - ib \partial_{\overline{z}}\right ) \\
& = & 2iab \omega\left (\partial_{\overline{z}}, \partial_z \right ) \\
& = & -4\alpha ab.
\end{eqnarray*}

I don't see how positive-definiteness of the form can be discerned here.  We would need $a$ and $b$ to be different signs, let alone nonzero.  I have also carried out the computation sticking with the coordinates $(x,p)$, but I get a similar issue when I do this (I'm omitting this from my question because I don't think it's any more illuminating than what I have written above).  What am I missing here?

For reference, this is a question from Brian Hall's [Quantum Theory for Mathematicians](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/146147115X).  It's in the final chapter discussing quantization of observables for manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z = x-i\alpha p$ then $dx = \tfrac{1}{2}(dz + d\bar{z})$ and $dp = \tfrac{i}{2\alpha}(dz - d\bar{z})$ so $\omega = dp \wedge dx = \tfrac{i}{2\alpha} dz \wedge d\bar{z}$.

You wrote $X = a\partial_z + b\partial_{\bar{z}}$ and $JX=ia\partial_z-ib\partial_{\bar{z}}$, and this gives $\omega(X,JX) = \tfrac{1}{\alpha}ab$.

But remember the $(x,p)$ coordinates: $\partial_x = \partial_z + \partial_{\bar{z}}$ and $\partial_p = -i\alpha(\partial_z - \partial_{\bar{z}})$, so $$X = A\partial_x + B\partial_p = (A-i\alpha B)\partial_z + (A+i\alpha B)\partial_{\bar{z}}$$ meaning $a = A-i\alpha B$ and $b = A+i\alpha B$, so we get $$\omega(X,JX) = \tfrac{1}{\alpha}(A-i\alpha B)(A+i \alpha B) = \tfrac{1}{\alpha}(A^2 + \alpha^2 B^2)$$
which is positive-definite.

Comment: I don't see how your complexified form $\omega$ is correct.  I computed $\omega \equiv 2i\alpha d\overline{z} \wedge dz$ based on the correspondence $\omega(\partial_x, \cdot) = -dp$ and $\omega(\partial_p, \cdot) = dx$.  Also, can you please perform the computation that $\omega(X,JX) = \frac{1}{\alpha}ab$?  This is another place I'm stuck.

Comment: We have $dz = dx - i\alpha dp$ and $d\bar{z} = dx + i\alpha dp$; my expressions for $dx$ and $dp$ follow, and $\omega = dp \wedge dx$ is expanded using bi-linearity and skew-symmetry of $\wedge$. Using the expressions for $\partial_x$ and $\partial_p$ in terms of $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$ you can also check that $\omega(\partial_p, \partial_x) = 1$ and $\omega(\partial_x, \cdot) = -dp$ and $\omega(\partial_p, \cdot) = dx$ hold. The computation that $\omega(X,JX) = \tfrac{1}{\alpha}ab$ is just using the skew-symmetry and bi-linearity of $\omega$, and the definitions of $X$ and $JX$.

Comment: Note that $\partial_z = \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\partial_x + \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}\partial_p$ while $dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial p} dp$ (note the forward and backward transformations being used); maybe this is where you got confused?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I realize now that I computed $dz$ incorrectly.  Should've done this based on the conditions $dz(\partial_z)=1$ and $dz(\partial_{\overline{z}})=0$ instead of trying to use $\omega$.